# RecordRTC.js - record screen with mic and speaker (virtual output) - windows + chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, recordrtc

I'm using absolutely amazing library to record screen with audio from mic on chrome and Windows 7 - RecordRTC.js.

I have a use case now when my web app needs to record a browser tab contains a video (with audio) and my audio comment (from my mic).

Everything works fine with the browser being recorded and my audio comment however, I don't know how to add extra audio from the video playing in the browser (speaker).

The function I'm using is:

```
function captureAudioPlusScreen(config) {
    if (navigator.getDisplayMedia) {
        navigator.getDisplayMedia({
            video: true
        }).then(screenStream => {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true}).then(function(mic) {

                screenStream.addTrack(mic.getTracks()[0]);

                config.onMediaCaptured(screenStream);

                addStreamStopListener(screenStream, function() {
                    btnStartRecording.onclick();
                });

                setVideoURL(screenStream, true);
            });
        }).catch(function(error) {
            config.onMediaCapturingFailed(error);
        });
    } else if (navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
            video: true
        }).then(screenStream => {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true}).then(function(mic) {
                screenStream.addTrack(mic.getTracks()[0]);

                config.onMediaCaptured(screenStream);

                addStreamStopListener(screenStream, function() {

                    btnStartRecording.onclick();
                });

                setVideoURL(screenStream, true);
            });
        }).catch(function(error) {
            config.onMediaCapturingFailed(error);
        });
    } else {
        var error = 'getDisplayMedia API are not supported in this browser.';
        config.onMediaCapturingFailed(error);
        alert(error);
    }
}
```

Any help would be super appreciated.